# Code example using PHP library to retrieve payments from stripe account

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am not sure how to include the PHP stripe api library into my php file in order to get a list of transactions from my stripe account. I have downloaded the lib source and extracted the contents to a folder into which I saved a file called getStripeTransList.php with the following code inside:-

The error I get is

> Class Stripe not found

I have adjusted the code as follows:-

```
<?php

require "Stripe.php";
require "Charge.php";

Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_...");
$transList = Stripe\Charge::all(array("limit" => 3));
var_dump($transList);
```

The error I now get is 'Stripe\ApiResource' not found in Charge.php.
Charge.php looks like this:-

```
<?php

namespace Stripe;

class Charge extends ApiResource

{
    /**
     * @param string $id The ID of the charge to retrieve.
```

with class APIResource declared in APIResource.php. I get the feeling that I have not installed or configured the stripe PHP API library correctly with all these dependencies appearing? How should the library be installed. I try not to use Composer, but will if that is the only way.

Comment: make sure your require path is correct and check namespace in Stripe.php

Comment: The Stripe.php file is in the same sub directory. I noticed the namespace in Stripe.php is Stripe. Aha! Appending the 'Stripe\' namespace to the class to qualify it, worked. Not really worked much with namespaces. Thanks.

Comment: I have adjusted the code as follows:-

Comment: okay happy to heard worked. So mark as up my comment :)

Comment: Sorry about the comments going wrong. Finger problems. I have added more to the question via answer.

Comment: Don't add more information as answer, edit your question instead.

Comment: @user2484775 please follow the rules and ethics in this community thanks.

Comment: You need to include the entire Stripe library: `require_once("/path/to/stripe-php/init.php");`. Trying to include some files directly (such as `Charge.php`) will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not including the Stripe PHP bindings correctly.

If you're using Composer, you'd simply include Composer's `autoload.php` file:

```
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
```

If you installed the library manually, you'd need to include the `init.php` file:

```
require_once("/path/to/stripe-php/init.php");
```

Once the library has been included, you will be able to [list all charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_charges) like this:

```
$charges = \Stripe\Charge::all();
foreach ($charges->data as $charge) {
    // Do something with $charge
}
```

Note that all "list" API calls only return a finite number of resources. To retrieve the entire list, you might need to issue several API calls with [pagination parameters](https://stripe.com/docs/api#pagination) to pick up where the previous call left off.

If you're using the latest versions of the bindings (3.9.0), you can also use the new auto-pagination feature:

```
$charges = \Stripe\Charge::all();
foreach ($charges->autoPagingIterator() as $charge) {
    // Do something with $charge
}
```

This will automatically iterate over all charges, querying new pages as needed.

Comment: thanks alot @Ywain for your answer ... please can you tell me that how can i get unlimited data